# prevent values in Fields of redux-from on unsuccessfull api response

Tags: reactjs, forms, api, redux, redux-form

**I want to prevent values in fields of redux-form on unsuccess API response to review user what he has entered wrong but when I submit the form all the values become clear I try destoryonUnmount method in reudForm() but this is not a good approach**

```
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { SubmissionError } from "redux-form";

import Login from "../../components/Login";

function LoginPage() {
  
  const Formdata = async (Formvalues) => {
    const responsive = await dispatch(Action.Login(Formvalues));

    if (!!responsive.payload.accessToken) {
    } else {
      throw new SubmissionError({
        _error: "Login Failed",
      });
    }
  };
  return <Login onSubmit={Formdata} />;
}

export default LoginPage;
```

**here is my form configuration**

```
const validate = (values) => {
  const errors = {};
  const requiredFields = ["email", "password"];
  requiredFields.forEach((field) => {
    if (!values[field]) {
      errors[field] = "Required";
    }
  });

  return errors;
};

const LoginComponent = reduxForm({
  form: "LoginForm",
  validate,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
})(Login);

export default LoginComponent;
```

Comment: i identified problem values disappear when we make API call so how i  prevent these values

Answer (score 0):

**I have found the solution by searching it for two to three days because no one answer it
in my routes file, I have to use either React.pureComponent or momo**

```
 import React, { Suspense, memo } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
// Import Containers
  
import Login from "../container/Login";
  
 

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="Loading......">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Authenciated(Login)} />
        


        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default memo(Routes);
```